# Understanding Object.create() using MDN article

Tags: javascript

I took the following code from MDN article on `Object.create()` to understand the same.

```
// Shape - superclass
function Shape() {
  this.x = 0;
  this.y = 0;
}

function Rectangle() {
  Shape.call(this);
}

Rectangle.prototype = Object.create(Shape.prototype);
Rectangle.prototype.constructor = Rectangle;
var rect = new Rectangle();
console.log(rect.y);
```

I commented-out the following two lines and still works as expected. Then what is the significance of `Object.create()` method in this code?. Why this method has been demonstrated in the example?

```
Rectangle.prototype = Object.create(Shape.prototype);
Rectangle.prototype.constructor = Rectangle;
```

Comment: You omitted some very key parts of the example - parts that define `Shape`'s prototype, and parts showing `rect`'s ability to call those functions. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create

Comment: @CertainPerformance : Is the line `Rectangle.prototype.constructor = Rectangle` really needed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This statement makes `Rectangle`'s prototype a new object that inherits from `Shape`'s prototype.  Because `rect` inherits from `Rectangle`'s prototype (since it was constructed using `new Rectangle()`), this means that `rect` inherits indirectly from `Shape`'s prototype.

However, the code in your question does not actually assign anything to `Shape`'s prototype, so it will run just fine without doing this, making the code a bit... silly.  It demonstrates the technique without demonstrating the purpose of the technique.<sup>1</sup>

Adding this to the example changes things:

```
Shape.prototype.getPosition = function getPosition() {
    return [this.x, this.y];
};
```

Then, `rect.getPosition()` would return `[0, 0]` as `rect` has inherited the method from `Rectangle`'s prototype, which has in turn inherited it from `Shape`'s prototype.

---

<sup>1</sup> As pointed out in a comment, the code in your question omits part of the original code sample, and those parts do demonstrate why you would have one prototype object inherit from another.  Removing parts of a sample can render the sample useless, which appears to be what happened here.

Answer (score 0):

In fact in this MDN example, prototype of `Rectangle` is a new object that inherits from prototype of `Shape`.

Just because of inheritance of `rect` from prototype of `Rectangle` actually `rect` inherits from prototype of `Shape`.

Anything doesn't assign to prototype of `Shape` so it run and do nothing.

Put for example a method inside prototype of `Shape`:

```
Shape.prototype.move = function(x, y) {
  this.x += x;
  this.y += y;
  console.info('Shape moved.');
};
```

Then, `rect.move(newX, newY)` will return something.